# How to turn adjacent into a verb

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word which means "to make adjacent to," or a conjugation of adjacent that would satisfy that?

For example:

The editor *moved that paragraph to make it adjacent to this one*.  Is there a way to make the bold words into a less awkward phrase, so that the sentence would read "The editor [mystery verb here] these two paragraphs"?

Comment: What circumstances are you using it for? If you're talking about nodes in a graph, you could use *"connect"*? If you're talking about making Germany adjacent to Russia, you could use *"partition Poland"*?

Comment: There isn't, as far as I know, a verb which means "to make adjacent to" in an absolute sense; it all depends on contextual meaning. Do you have an example of context, possibly?

Comment: Can you specify adjacent 'to what', or the object you wish to make adjacent

Comment: @StoneyB I think juxtapose may be what I am looking for.

Comment: *Adjacent* means “lying next to”, so the corresponding verb must be *to place next to*.

Comment: @StoneyB: your sugggestion is plainly correct; why not put it in the nice big Answer box?

Comment: @TimLymington As you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Juxtapose* may be used of one entity to another, or of two or more entities.

> The editor juxtaposed that paragraph to this one.
>
> He juxtaposed the two paragraphs, and added a brief transition at the head of the second.

There are also *adject* and *appose*, but neither is in much contemporary use

Comment: Since I already effectively accepted this answer by implementing it in what I was working on, I think I can give you a check mark.

Comment: The word "juxtapose" has the purpose of highlighting a _contrasting characteristic_, for ironic or dramatic purpose.

Answer (score 2):

‘Juxtapose’ isn't bad, but has something of an imprecise or arbitrary connotation.  Things have been put next to each other… and that happens to have occurred *here*… but they might just as easily have been put somewhere else...

I would suggest the term *collocate*, which (a) is already in common grammatical use, and (b) has a rather more definite sense of intention.  The two paragraphs (or whatever) have been brought together and placed at *this* point for some specific purpose.  *This position* is somehow definitively desirable, for *both* items as a combination, not merely as two individual things placed side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the verb **to abut** (2nd sense and example).

> Definitions:
>
> 1. to be adjacent; touch or join at the edge or border (often followed by on, upon, or against)
> 2. to cause to abut
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. *This piece of land abuts on a street*.
> 2. *Click the left-most button underneath “Distribute Spacing” to abut the top/bottom edges of the rectangles*.

Answer (score 0):

adjacent is an adjective that describes a state of proximity between 2 entities.

In order to "make" something "adjacent" to another, you can say something along the line of:

to move something adjacent to something else

Answer (score -1):

You can use "conjoin", which comes the closest in meaning to *that for which you are asking*.

Answer (score -4):

'next to'--'he inserted that paragraph next to this one.'

Comment: It's also not a verb, which is what the OP is looking for. "*He nexted the two pictures ... ?*"

Comment: He inserted that paragraph next to this one. Plain talk!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Next to is not "one word" as the question was requesting and tagged.  I'd be fine with two syllables, as long as they don't have a space between them.  Heck, I'd even go for one syllable!